# Is there a Perl equivalent of Buildout or RVM?

Tags: perl, build-automation, dependency-management

I've been using Python's [Buildout](http://www.buildout.org/) for a while and I really like it.  My company has a lot of systems developed in Perl and I'm wondering if there is something similar to either Python's Buildout or Ruby's [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) available for Perl. My goal is to be able to automate deployments, development environment setup, and manage dependencies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I must admit I have heard today the first time about the software you named, but reading the introduction material there is a difference in purpose between Buildout and RVM. An equivalent of the former is [`Shipwright`](http://p3rl.org/Shipwright), of the latter – [`perlbrew`](http://p3rl.org/perlbrew).

Comment: Thanks, I will check those out. Unless something else comes along I will accept this answer as correct.

Comment: is Shipwright something that you use? I've been playing with it and I haven't really been able to accomplish much of anything. The documentation is lacking. I see how it gets all of my dependencies bundled together, but then what? How do I get from a vessel to a deployed working product?